# MySQL - How do i get the Mode from a group by Select

Tags: mysql, magento

I have created a bunch of MySQL script that import products into magento, i have used a GROUP BY to group products into configurable products

in the past, i have used `MIN()` to get the lowest price in the group and used that value as the price for the configurable products but as of late there have been some cases like this

```
Simple Product ID | Price ($)
------------------------------
      1001        |   10
      1002        |   10
      1003        |    5
      1004        |   10
      1005        |   20
      1006        |   10
```

in this situation, when i create the configurable product, `MIN(Price)` would return 5, i only just learned that with configurable products i could have a negative difference which means now i need to change my code so instead of getting minimum (5) i get the Mode (10)

I figured i just have to replace the `MIN()` in my query with MODE() but there doesn't seem to be a MODE() function for MySQL, here's an example of the query i'm using

```
INSERT INTO import_table
(
    product_id, stock_id, price
)
SELECT ODT.product_id, ODT.stock_id, MIN(ODT.Price)
FROM org_data_table AS ODT
GROUP BY ODT.stock_id
```

Is there a function that already exists to get the Mode? if not then what do i need to do to get it, i would like to just change the `MIN()` part of my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the MODE of price through below query

```
SELECT ODT.Price as price, count(ODT.Price) AS cnt 
FROM org_data_table  as ODT
GROUP BY ODT.price 
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return the `Price` **Mode** value, and then you can utilize this in SELECT statement as below so you can insert the **Mode** value, see below query:

```
INSERT INTO import_table
(
    product_id, stock_id, price
)
SELECT ODT.product_id, ODT.stock_id, (SELECT ODT.Price as price 
FROM org_data_table  as ODT
GROUP BY ODT.price 
ORDER BY count(ODT.Price) DESC 
LIMIT 1) as price
FROM org_data_table AS ODT
GROUP BY ODT.stock_id
```

Comment: there was a slight problem with the bottom query which was fixed by removing `count(ODT.Price) AS cnt` and replaceing `cnt` with `count(ODT.Price)` the sub select could only return 1 field) but it works perfectly, thanks

Comment: @Memor-X Oh yes, I did not actually tested that, that change is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a little tricky because MODEs can have multiple prices -- if 2 prices have the same count, then they are both considered the MODE.

This query should return any records from the org_data_table whose price is in the MODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Product_Id, T.Stock_Id, T.Price
FROM org_data_table T 
  JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, Price
    FROM org_data_table
    GROUP BY Price
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (
      SELECT Max(cnt)  
      FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, Price
        FROM org_data_table
        GROUP BY Price
        ) t
      )
  ) T2 ON T.Price = T2.Price
```

And here is some sample Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1a2/1

Obviously you can add:

```
INSERT INTO import_table (product_id, stock_id, price)
```

before the query to insert the records.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how my query would work (using the example you provided in sql fiddle) is that it would return 2 items, one of stock 1 and one of stock id 2 but their prices would be the Mode of the 2 groups.....however you query does help for another matter as it lists all the product_id's and stock_ids which match to the Mode (or Modes in the schema you made), you query (with slight adjustments) will help out when debug problems like why i'm not getting the expect Mode, thank you

Comment: @Memor-X -- glad we could help.  Be sure to realize, that MODES can contain multiple values -- hence using LIMIT 1 may produce incorrect results.  Best of luck!